# Swift: Can we put a version check around the module import statement?

Tags: ios, swift, import, module, importerror

I want to add some SwiftUI code to a project that still supports iOS 12 as minimum deployment version.

To keep the code segregation and prevent the @available checks with each of new class/struct/extension, I wanted to create a framework with iOS 14 as minimum supported version.

Now the problem is, if I import the new module, I will get the following error:

***Compiling for iOS 12.0, but module 'Cart' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 14.0***

I understand that it's not possible to directly import the new module in a iOS 12 project. Is there any way to import the module using a #available check e.g.

```
#if available(iOS 14.0, *)
import iOS14Module
#endif
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As of today this is not possible. You will either need to find a new library or fork this one and lower the minimum deployment target of it before you can use it in your project.

Comment: As I mentioned, lowering the minimum deployment target is as good as having the code with @available checks.  But thanks for your reply.